# Qt Override class properties on control deserealization

Tags: c++, qt, class, properties, deserialization

Im trying to make a simple control serealization/deserialization, and i came up with the following code (.cpp)

```
#include "serializer.h"
#include "QMetaProperty"
#include "QTextStream"
#include "QDebug"

Serializer::Serializer(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

bool Serializer::Serialize(QObject *object,QString name) {
 QDomDocument doc;
 QDomElement root = doc.createElement(object->metaObject()->className());
 doc.appendChild(root);

 for(int i = 0; i < object->metaObject()->propertyCount(); i++)
 {
  QMetaProperty prop = object->metaObject()->property(i);
  QString propName = prop.name();
  if(propName == "objectName")
   continue;
  QDomElement el = doc.createElement(propName);
  QVariant value = object->property(propName.toLatin1().data());
  QDomText txt;
  if (object->metaObject()->property(i).typeName() != "QByteArray") {
   txt = doc.createTextNode( value.toString() );
  } else {
   txt = doc.createTextNode(object->metaObject()->property(i).typeName());
  }
   el.appendChild(txt);
   root.appendChild(el);
 }


  QFile f(name);
  f.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text);
  QTextStream stream(&f);
  doc.save(stream, 2);
  f.close();
  return true;
}

bool Serializer::_deserializeObject(QIODevice* input, QObject* object)
{
    QDomDocument doc;
    if (!doc.setContent(input))
        return false;
    QDomElement root = doc.documentElement();
    qDebug() << object->metaObject()->propertyCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < object->metaObject()->propertyCount(); i++)
    {
        QMetaProperty prop = object->metaObject()->property(i);
        QString propName = prop.name();
        if(propName == "objectName")
            continue;
        QDomNodeList nodeList = root.elementsByTagName(propName);
        if(nodeList.length() < 1)
            continue;
        QDomNode node = nodeList.at(0);
        QVariant value = object->property(propName.toLatin1().data());
        QString v = node.toElement().text();

        object->setProperty(propName.toLatin1().data(), QVariant(v));
    }
    return true;
}
```

.h file :

```
#ifndef SERIALIZER_H
#define SERIALIZER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDomDocument>
#include <QFile>

class Serializer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Serializer(QObject *parent = 0);
    bool Serialize(QObject *object, QString name);
    template<class T>
    T* deserialize(QIODevice *input)
    {
        T* object = new T();
        if(_deserializeObject(input, object))
            return object;
        delete object;
        return NULL;
    }


    bool _deserializeObject(QIODevice* input, QObject* object);
signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // SERIALIZER_H
```

So after i serialize for example some button, to the xml file i wanna deserialize it, i do it like so:

```
QFile f(fname);
f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QPushButton *ds = s.deserialize<QPushButton>(&f);
f.close();
```

The debug output gives me a lot of property errors on conversion

```
setProperty: Property "modal" invalid, read-only or does not exist
setProperty: Property "frameGeometry" invalid, read-only or does not exist
setProperty: Property "normalGeometry" invalid, read-only or does not exist
setProperty: Property "x" invalid, read-only or does not exist
setProperty: Property "y" invalid, read-only or does not exist
setProperty: Property "frameSize" invalid, read-only or does not exist
setProperty: Property "width" invalid, read-only or does not exist
setProperty: Property "height" invalid, read-only or does not exist
setProperty: Property "rect" invalid, read-only or does not exist
setProperty: Property "childrenRect" invalid, read-only or does not exist
setProperty: Property "childrenRegion" invalid, read-only or does not exist
setProperty: Property "isActiveWindow" invalid, read-only or does not exist
setProperty: Property "focus" invalid, read-only or does not exist
```

So my question, is there a way to somehow do a proper conversion, or should i subclass QPushButton and make those properties public? How do i override those properties in my subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to try to save all the properties.

[`QMetaProperty`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaproperty.html) has lots of flags that could help you filter the properties that should be saved (non-"stored" and non-"writable" properties should be avoided).

See also [Qt's Property System](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html).

For example, the properties `x`, `y` and `width`, `height` are non-`writable`, but are respectively parts of the `pos` and `size` properties, which are `writable`, but non-`stored`, because they are themselves parts of the larger property `geometry` which is the only one you really need to save and restore, and you can check that is this property is both `stored` and `writable`.

Comment: But for example if i need to save coordinates: x,y and width,height? Because i need to know the position etc. So i need to restore it

Comment: @SirLanceloaaat I edited the answer to explain why `stored` and `writable` properties should be enough.